# Alert Screen after power on Xperia Z

Tags: sony-xperia-z

I powered off my xperia z and powered on again. A progress bar with an alert icon has appeared on screen and didn't disappear until now(about 20 min). What's that?

If I need to flash the phone, can I somehow create a backup from files in internal memory?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that it appeared but is now gone and the phone is working fine? Please clarify what your actual question is.

Comment: No. It is still showing this screen. what does this icon mean at all?

Comment: Is the progress bar moving? Could be an OTA update?

Comment: If it hasn't disappeared now, I'd say it is a rom problem...

Comment: On the photo, there's not much to see. Could you provide a clearer shot with more details (and less mirror effects)?

Comment: @Izzy Please see this http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/4828ec2048c38575181a3fa4e953ff39/51ead254/2/0/0/4/7/7/4/xperia_z.jpg (in this topic: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302976)

Comment: Sorry: the first link is "gone", and the image in that XDA thread doesn't reveal more (maybe there isn't more to be revealed? Is the triangle and the progress bar all that's shown, no additional text, nothing?)